# Copying the contents of source blocks to clipboard

Tags: org-mode

Suppose our buffer reads:

```
* Test
#+BEGIN_SRC mathematica
Manipulate[Plot[{x^{a-1}, E^{-x}}, {x, 0, 10}], {a, 0, 10}]
#+END_SRC

#+BEGIN_SRC mathematica
2+2
#+END_SRC

#+BEGIN_SRC mathematica
E^{-2}
#+END_SRC
```

Is there a way to copy all of the source blocks so that something like the following gets copied to your clipboard?

```
Manipulate[Plot[{x^{a-1}, E^{-x}}, {x, 0, 10}], {a, 0, 10}]
2+2
E^{-2}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a function that will copy the contents of all the blocks in a subtree. You could also add some logic to only copy a certain kind, e.g.if you mix languages.

```
(defun org-copy-blocks ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((code ""))
    (save-restriction
      (org-narrow-to-subtree)
      (org-babel-map-src-blocks nil
    (setq code (concat code (org-no-properties body)))))
    (kill-new code)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Not quite what you're asking for, but org-mode provides the function `org-babel-tangle`, which extracts all the source blocks in a file and saves them into a single file. That might get you what you need. If not, you could write a function to call `org-babel-tangle`, then copy the contents of the generated file into the clipboard.